# Angular2 ngIf does not work

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am trying to hide an img if the route is not active. I have tried:

```
<div class="sidebar-nav-item dashboard-item" routerLinkActive="active" #rlaDashboardW="routerLinkActive">
        <a routerLink="/core/dashboard">
          <span class="helper"></span>
          <div class="re-full-height icon">
            <img class="nav-icon" src="{{ rlaDashboardW.isActive ? './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg' : './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon.svg'}}"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="re-full-height">
            <span> Dashboard </span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="separator-container">
          <img *ngIf="{{rlaDashboardW.isActive}}" src="./assets/navigation/navigation-separator-wide-active.svg" />
          <img src="./assets/navigation/navigation-separator-wide.svg"  />
        </div>
      </div>
```

but go this error: http://pastebin.com/TPXZU3BD

if I try:

```
<div class="sidebar-nav-item dashboard-item" routerLinkActive="active" #rlaDashboardW="routerLinkActive">
        <a routerLink="/core/dashboard">
          <span class="helper"></span>
          <div class="re-full-height icon">
            <img class="nav-icon" src="{{ rlaDashboardW.isActive ? './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg' : './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon.svg'}}"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="re-full-height">
            <span> Dashboard </span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="separator-container">
          <img *ngIf="rlaDashboardW.isActive" src="./assets/navigation/navigation-separator-wide-active.svg" />
          <img src="./assets/navigation/navigation-separator-wide.svg"  />
        </div>
      </div>
```

I get error: http://pastebin.com/wsGLqNx4

NOTE: the difference between the two snippets is that in the first one I use interpolation and in the second one I bind directly to the template variable.

NOTE2: I am experiencing similar issues with ngClass so I believe this is a global issue - will investigate and update

Answer (score 0):

This error is occuring when you do not import FormsModule in your app.module.ts and in your current module. Be sure to import it in both to get it work.

Also, the error message you send us are not related to the code you provide us. If you want good help next time, try to provide us the good part ;-)

Comment: I have FormsModule imported in App.Module, as well as in SharedModule as an export ( SharedModule is imported in the CoreModule where this template resides ), as well as in Core.Module as a separate import ... Also those errors are what I get when I run the two snippets ... if I remove the snippets I don't get an error => the errors are related to the code :)

Comment: I think there is a problem using binding variables in ngIf/ngClass expressions ( I have a similar problem with ngClass )

Comment: First, you do not need to extrapolte variable, so *ngIf='yourVar'. Then, TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined is not really related to your current code.

Comment: Look at the second snippet of code ... in it I use *ngIf="rlaDashboardW.isActive" ... So I try without interpolation and I still get an error. The "toUpperCase" of undefined is probably when Angular tries to do something with my interpolation which obviously does not work. As I said removing the **ngIf** directive in both cases results in clean execution without errors :)

Comment: Also I have the same problem when using **ngClass** and a template variable so I am now pretty sure there is a problem when using template variables in expressions for directives

Comment: can you share more code from your Component? How is rlaDashboardW.isActive obtained and initialized?

Comment: it is the first line of both snippets ... **#rlaDashboardW="routerLinkActive"**